# Flickr API OAuth Access Token request and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, oauth, flickr, same-origin-policy

## Context

I'm trying to get an **Access Token** from the Flickr API using their their [OAuth specification](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html).

The first step to get an Access Token is to obtain a [Request Token](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html#request_token). I successfully manage to generate a correctly signed and valid URL to request this token: when I copy/paste the generated URL in my browser, I get the correct response.

## Problem

As this part doesn't concern the user, I'm trying to get the Request Token by making a simple Ajax call:

```
console.log(baseURL + "?" + requestURL);
// When I copy/paste the log result in my browser, it works.

$.ajax({
    url: baseURL,
    type: 'GET',
    data: requestURL,
    done: function(data) {
        console.log('Request Token data', data);
    }
});
```

The problem is that I get an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** issue:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.flickr.com/...
Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've tried using **dataType: 'jsonp'** as a parameter of the Ajax call without any success:

```
GET http://www.flickr.com/... 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to implement Oauth 1.0 through just javascript without any server side script. Since the flickr's new authentication process is based on Oauth 1.0a. You got to use a server-side script.